# Reordable photo gallery - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a layout to build here and i have no idea how to achieve this with jetpack compose.

Its a Photo Gallery, like a grid, and when the user press the photo, it have a drag and drop to reorder the picture list.
Another thing is: the first photo of the list need to be centralized like the sample:
[image: sample here]

Comment: Drag and drop is pretty complicated stuff and there is still no official simple solution to that. I've implemented drag&drop on LazyList for our app based on this example from google, you should probably start there: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/LazyGridDragAndDropDemo.kt